# finding words that contain only 3 characters using sed in a file

Tags: sed, words

I need to print only words that consist of 3 characters, however the word document is a numbered list.

Here's the exact question that I have to answer:

> Using the `sed` command with `[[:lower:]]` character class on the `animals` file, find all the animal names that are only three characters long *(3 marks)*.

This is what i have tried:

```
cat animals | sed '/{[:lower:]].../d'  
cat animals | sed '/{[:lower:]]/d' 
sed '/[[:lower:]]{3}/d' animals
```

This is the file I am trying to find the words from (the `animals` file):

```
01. aardvark
02. badger
03. cow
04. dog
05. elephant
06. fox
07. goose
08. horse
09. iguana
10. jackal
11. koala
12. lamb
13. mongoose
14. narwhal
15. onyx
16. pig
17. quail
18. rat
19. snake
20. tiger
21. umbrellabird
22. vulture
23. walrus
24. xerus
25. yak
26. zebra
```

i have just found out the code cannot have the [[:lower:]] in it more than once is there a way to do this??

Comment: start with the sed manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html

Comment: Get familiar with regular expressions.

Comment: this is what i have tried so far, didnt put them in the first post as i didnt expect to get a reply.

Comment: [clf18ftf@sshgateway ~]$ cat animals | sed '/{[:lower:]].../d'
[clf18ftf@sshgateway ~]$ cat animals | sed '/{[:lower:]]/d'
[clf18ftf@sshgateway ~]$ sed '/[[:lower:]]{3}/d' animals

Comment: What is the format of the data file? Is it one word per line?

Comment: i have added a screenshot of the whole file

Comment: Out of interest what do you think the `d` operator (last character in the various `sed` attempts you've posted) does? ISTM you've copied that from somewhere without quite realising what it does.

Comment: Why this question wants you to use `sed` for the virtue of using `sed`, I have no idea. It's far easier to just use `grep`.

Comment: @NasirRiley because that is what is being assessed.

Comment: the 1st 2 have silly error `{` instead of `[`.  You need to start using Unix every day; learn the basics like how to list a file. If you learn it you will be so glad, as it will save you a lot of effort in your future. As a teacher I understand that giving you the answer will not help you. It will result in you being more stuck on the next assignment. You will have to go back to the previous assignments and do them your self: get full understanding. Read the manuals and practice, (look up cat, file redirection, regular expressions, grep, sed `man sed`). The 3rd example is close, but what is d?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I understand that but it would be better to assess it with an exercise where `sed` is actually the best option. In this case, it certainly isn't and I can't see any reason why anyone would want to use `sed` when `grep` makes a lot more sense. I can dig a whole in the ground with a spoon but it makes far more sense to use a shovel.

Comment: @NasirRiley The OP is in an assessment prison. When in prison, sometime all one has is a spoon.

Comment: @ ctrl-alt-delor. Again, I understand that but if the assessment wants him to use `sed`, it would make more sense to have do it when it when it's the best choice. Your analogy is flawed because he's never going to be in a position where he can't use `grep` which in this case, is far better.

Comment: I have to use sed as that is how im being assessed, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is a stream editor, which means that it reads in text, edits it, and outputs the result. It doesn't necessarily need to work on files, just streams of text. (In your case the stream of text comes from a file, so there's no practical difference.)

Using `sed` you have a couple of options

1. Delete all lines that do not have exactly three consecutive lowercase letters, leaving the rest to be passed through (and printed).
2. Print only lines that contain exactly three consecutive lowercase letters.

In either case you'll need to ensure that the three are preceded by a space and have nothing after them.

This will match words of four (or more) characters and delete the matching line. Notice we don't bind the ends of the sequence so they will happily match in the middle of a longer sequence

```
sed '/[[:lower:]][[:lower:]][[:lower:]][[:lower:]]/d' animals
```

This will work on the file as given but it doesn't take into account the possibility that there might be animals of two (or even just one) letter. (Think "ox", for example). So we need to knock those out. At this point we need to tell `sed` there are multiple operations to be applied to each line, in turn. We also need to introduce a new character `$` which states that the regular expression must bind to the end-of-line:

- If we find four characters in a row, delete the line
- If we find a space, two letters, and then end-of-line, delete the line
- If we find a space, one letter, and then end-of-line, delete the line

This can be written out in long form like this:

```
sed -e '/[[:lower:]][[:lower:]][[:lower:]][[:lower:]]/d' -e '/ [[:lower:]][[:lower:]]$/d' -e '/ [[:lower:]]$/d' animals
```

If you have a suitable version of `sed` you can collapse this down into a more readable form. (Look for the `-r` flag.)

Comment: much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` and I got the result you wanted with this:

```
sed 's/^[[:digit:]]\{2\}[[:punct:]][[:space:]]\([[:lower:]]\{3\}\)/\1/gm' animals.txt | sed '/[[:lower:]]\{4\}/d'
```

It does these steps:

1. Find the lines that starts with 2 digits, followed by a punctuation ("."), a space and then a word with at least 3 lower case characters;
2. Within that line, select the group of lower case characters matched;
3. With the result from the previous step, delete the words with 4 or more lower case characters.

The output has only the words with exactly 3 lower case characters:

```
cow
dog
fox
pig
rat
yak
```

For reference, the GNU sed uses [this regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way to do this would be something like this:

```
$ sed -n '/^....[a-z]\{3\}$/p' animals
03. cow
04. dog
06. fox
16. pig
18. rat
25. yak
```

To meet the requirement that you use `[[:lower:]]` you could modify the above like so:

```
$ sed -n '/^....[[:lower:]]\{3\}$/p' animals
03. cow
04. dog
06. fox
16. pig
18. rat
25. yak
```

You could also switch out the `....` for a explicitly sized sequence:

```
$ sed -n '/^.\{4\}[[:lower:]]\{3\}$/p' animals
03. cow
04. dog
06. fox
16. pig
18. rat
25. yak
```

#### References

- https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: Maybe `sed -E '/ [[:lower:]]{3}$/!d'`, or, if the sed in use allow it: `sed -E '/\<[[:lower:]]{3}\>/!d'` are simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. The basic idea of matching 3 elements is in the right direction.

There is a syntax error for BRE in that the `{}` need backslash (or use `-E`).

However, your regex: `[[:lower:]]\{3\}` will match anything with three or **more** characters.

You need to **anchor** the regex, maybe from the `space` () to the `end` (`$`):

```
$ <infile sed -n '/ [[:lower:]]\{3\}$/p'
```

Note that the command will not print by default and only on matching lines will `p`rint. That could be written the other way around:

```
$ <infile sed '/ [[:lower:]]\{3\}$/!d'
```

That is: print by default, on lines **not** matching, delete them (`d`).

Or, you can use word boundaries:

```
$ <infile sed '/\b[[:lower:]]\{3\}\b/!d'
```

Or:

```
$ <infile sed '/\<[[:lower:]]\{3\}\>/!d'
```

And, maybe, use ERE regex:

```
$ <infile sed -E '/\b[[:lower:]]{3}\b/!d'
```

If you need only the animals names, use this:

```
$ <infile sed -E '/.*\<([[:lower:]]{3})\>/!d;s//\1/'
cow
dog
fox
pig
rat
yak
```